# Python and ElementTree: How can I nest elements/subelements in an XML?

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, python-2.6, elementtree

## Background

I am using **Python 2.6**, **ElementTree**, and **SQLite3**. My script currently does the following:

- Connects to a database to retrieve information from tables/schema
- Adds necessary data to an XML tree
- Outputs a (currently incorrect) XML file

## Code

Here is how I've been retrieving schema data and adding elements to the XML. I do this with the `SOFTWARE_` and `TARGET_` tables. This is for the `SOFTWARE_` table:

```
software_attributes =  ["id", "functionalDesignationHardware", "hwfin", "identname", "partnumber",
                        "repfin", "targetHardwareID"]

software = db.cursor().execute("SELECT %s from SOFTWARE_" % ", ".join([i + "_" for i in software_attributes]))
software_Data = software.fetchall()
ID1 = db.cursor().execute("SELECT id_ from SOFTWARE_")
software_IDs = ID1.fetchall()

for sw in software_Data:
   sw_node = ET.SubElement(root, "Software")
   for s in range(1, len(software_attributes)):
      sw_node.set(software_attributes[s], str(sw[s]))
```

**UPDATED:** This is my code for the `TARGET_` table:

```
target_attributes = ["id", "functionalDesignationSoftware", "installscriptpathname", "ata", "status",
                     "swfin", "targetOSFC", "timestamp"]

target = db.cursor().execute("SELECT %s from TARGET_" % ", ".join([i + "_" for i in target_attributes]))
target_Data = target.fetchall()
ID2 = db.cursor().execute("SELECT id_ from TARGET_")
target_IDs = ID2.fetchall()

## CURRENTLY INCORRECT - only adds to the last created Software Element ##
for tg in target_Data:
   tg_node = ET.SubElement(sw_node, "TargetModule")
   for t in range(1, len(target_attributes)):
      tg_node.set(target_attributes[t], str(tg[t]))
```

This is how I'm storing the information from tables whose only purpose is to connect data from *other* tables. The `SOFTWARE_TARGET_` table connects `SOFTWARE_` to `TARGET_`. I'm storing its information in a dictionary:

```
software_target = db.cursor().execute("SELECT SOFTWARE1, TARGET2 from SOFTWARE_TARGET_")
software_target_Data = software_target.fetchall()

# Map SOFTWARE1 to TARGET2
separated_st_Data = {}
for item in software_target_Data:
    software1, target2 = item
    try:
        separated_st_Data[software1].append(target2)
    except KeyError:
        separated_st_Data[software1] = [target2]
```

## Attempts

So far, I have figured out how to set up my xml in the format:

```
<Software attribute="stuff" attribute2="Stuff"/>
<Software attribute="stuff" attribute2="Stuff"/>
<Target attribute="things" attribute2="Things"/>
```

But what I need is the following format:

```
<Software attribute="stuff" attribute2="Stuff"
    <Target attribute="things" attribute2="Things"/>
    <Target attribute="things" attribute2="Things"/>
</Software>
<Software attribute="stuff" attribute2="Stuff"/>
```

Which `Target` sub-elements go under which `Software` elements is determined by the information from the `SOFTWARE_TARGET_` table. I've found how to traverse my dictionary, like so:

```
depth=0
for k,v in sorted(separated_st_Data.items(),key=lambda x: x[0]):
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        print ("  ")*depth + ("%s" % k)
        walk_dict(v,depth+1)
    else:
        print ("  ")*depth + "%s %s" % (k, v)
```

## Question

How can I create an XML file that is formatted correctly (as noted in the **Attemps** section) based upon the information from the database's tables? I created the dictionary thinking I could use it for this purpose - please let me know if this is necessary.

**Notes**

[This](http://textdump.net/read/6872/) is what my dictionary created from the `SOFTWARE_TARGET_` table looks like. The keys represent the `id_` schema from `SOFTWARE_` and the values represent the `id_` schema from `TARGET_`. (Let me know if my terminology sounds off - databases confuse me sometimes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your `Target` elements (code not given in the question here), be sure you pass the `sw_node` to which they're intended to be attached as the first argument.

That is:

```
target_el = SubElement(sw_node, "Target")
```

instead of...

```
target_el = SubElement(root_node, "Target")
```

---

A typical pattern for code of this variety might have the following appearance (roughly; needs some testing, written for a DB-API driver using the `pyformat` paramstyle and won't work with others):

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * from SOFTWARE_")
for sw_item in cursor.fetchall():
  sw_el = SubElement(root_el, 'Software') ## STORING THE ELEMENT HERE
  sw_id = None
  for idx in range(len(cursor.description)):
    name = cursor.description[idx][0]
    if name == 'id':
      sw_id = sw_item[idx]
    sw_el.attrib[name] = sw_item[idx]
  ## QUERYING FOR CHILDREN HERE
  cursor.execute("SELECT TARGET_.*
                  FROM TARGET_, SOFTWARE_TARGET_
                  WHERE SOFTWARE_TARGET_.SOFTWARE1=%(sw_id)s
                    AND SOFTWARE_TARGET_.TARGET2=TARGET_.ID",
      sw_id=sw_id)
  for target_item in cursor.fetchall():
    # create a new target element
    target_el = SubElement(sw_el, 'Target')
    # assign attributes to that element
    for idx in range(len(cursor.description)):
      name = cursor.description[idx][0].rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
      target_el.attrib[name] = target_item[idx]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand how to add sub-elements in general - my problem is I'm not sure how to add certain `Target` elements to their respective `Software` elements based on the information provided in the `SOFTWARE_TARGET` table which links the two (not all `Software` elements are going to have a `Target` sub-element, whereas some will have multiple `Target` sub-elements). Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I grok all your code here. Is there a reason you aren't doing a query for associated Target elements, and iterate over them, as you process each Software element (and thus have a pointer to that element on hand)? Alternately, if you do just one join to create a structure that encapsulates that data, indexing into the structure should be trivial.

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm not sure I understand your suggestion fully - could you provide me a link where I can look into doing that?

Comment: I've added some pseudocode showing the pattern. Written from memory, will need some debugging, but shows the general mechanism.

Comment: I get the following error: `for idx in range(cursor.description):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got tuple.`

Comment: @Kimbluey, as I said, it's pseudocode. Treat it as such. Read it to understand what it's trying to do, and look up the docs for any part of it you don't understand.

Comment: @Kimbluey, ...that said, I've edited to fix that particular bug.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what `name = cursor.description[idx][0].rsplit('.', 1)[-1]` is doing here. `cursor.description`'s documentation isn't doing me much good so far but if you're tired of helping I can keep searching the web

Comment: @Kimbluey, ...so, `cursor.description` is a list of tuples; `0` is the index into that tuple for the name field, per the docs at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description -- and the `.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]` is taking the last `.`-separated segment, to change a name with a prefix like `software_.id` to `id`.

Comment: @Kimbluey, ...btw, it's less about searching the web in general -- I didn't use Google for any of this -- and more about reading the API docs for the modules in question (or, in this case, the DB-API docs).

Comment: I always look at the API documentation first, but I don't always like how they are written and I learn better with examples vs. reading the docs. Thanks for the link - it looks like the [same site I've been using](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html) so I don't know how I couldn't find that page. I like that *much* better than the page I was looking at. Also thanks for the explanation of that line, I've been playing with it to understand it better

Comment: Would it be *unacceptable* or *helpful* if I added my final code as another answer to this question for others to see?

Comment: Certainly acceptable; go right ahead. (The question still isn't a great one -- lots of implementation details, not very generalized, nowhere near a MCVE -- but figuring out _how_ to do it better isn't trivial).

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, almost forgot - here's the **final code** I have ended up using in my finished Python script (minus a few key elements of a complete script, of course):

```
software_attributes =  ["id", "partnumber", "identname", "functionalDesignationHardware", "hwfin", 
                        "targetHardwareID","repfin", "amendment"]

target_attributes = ["id", "swfin", "targetOSFC", "functionalDesignationSoftware", "installscriptpathname", 
                     "ata", "status","timestamp"]

sw_current = cursor.execute("SELECT %s from SOFTWARE_" % ", ".join([i + "_" for i in software_attributes]))
sw_current = sw_current.fetchall()
for sw_item in sw_current:
    current_sw_ID = sw_item[0]

    # Create Software XML Element
    sw_element = ET.SubElement(root, "Software")
    # Set Software attributes
    for s in range(1, len(software_attributes)):
        sw_element.set(software_attributes[s], str(sw_item[s]))

    # Get all Target IDs for current Software Element
    current_tg_IDs = cursor.execute("SELECT TARGET2 from SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE SOFTWARE1=?", (current_sw_ID,))
    current_tg_IDs = list(chain.from_iterable(current_tg_IDs.fetchall()))
    while len(current_tg_IDs) > 0:
        tg_id = current_tg_IDs.pop(0)
        tg_current = cursor.execute("SELECT %s from TARGET_ WHERE id_=?" % ", ".join([i + "_" for i in target_attributes]), (str(tg_id).strip('[]'),))
        tg_current = tg_current.fetchall()

        for tg_item in tg_current:
            # Create Target XML Element
            tg_element = ET.SubElement(sw_element, "TargetModule")
            # Set Target attributes
            for t in range(1, len(target_attributes)):
                tg_element.set(target_attributes[t], str(tg_item[t]))
```

**Note:** In my final attempt above, I did not end up using the dictionary approach as originally assumed in this question - my final approach is more efficient for my purposes. See the selected answer to this question for an example of an approach using dictionaries.